# Getting DNS servers on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, dns

I'm using the DnsQueryConfig Win32 function to get the DNS servers used by Windows. This works fine for IPv4 addresses, but what if the DNS servers have IPv6 addresses?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you're asking, be it finding the DNS servers of the local machine or a way to do DNS queries to IPv6 DNS servers

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an API in MSDN, but I did find this line command:

> [IPv6 dp6dns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916844.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Windows do you mean?

At least in Windows XP, there's no support for querying DNS servers over IPv6 transport, so the question is moot.

I don't know whether that's fixed in Vista.

Comment: Vista supports querying DNS servers over IPv6, but I don't believe that actually helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that Win32 function.  If you want an IPv6 address, you need to look for a "AAAA" DNS record vs. a "A" record.  Hopefully that helps some...